# Can we merge molecular-orbital and molecular-orbital-theory

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think it is quite hard to describe a molecular orbital without molecular orbital theory, since the former is a direct result of the latter. I would suggest making [molecular-orbital](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-orbital) a synonym of [molecular-orbital-theory](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-orbital-theory) since this has a more general meaning. Any opinions?

Comment: I agree with this, I don't see a necessity for there to be two tags.

Comment: I agree as well.

Comment: I think merging those tags sounds reasonable. What about the [tag:orbitals] tag? Should all the orbital-tags be unified or is a differentiation of general orbital matters and molecular orbital questions sensible?

Comment: looking at the [most popular question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/152/4945) there, it is actually about orbitals in general, i.e. the AO function. Also orbitals can be conceptual involved in non-computational manner, so merging it onto MO theory might be overkill.

Comment: @Martin I was more thinking along the lines of having a general orbital-tag instead of fractionating the subject, like maybe merging [tag:molecular-orbital] and [tag:molecular-orbital-theory] into [tag:orbitals]. But I understand that most questions about orbitals usually have a molecular-orbital-background, so I could see the good sense behind keeping the [tag:orbitals] tag and the [tag:molecular-orbital-theory] tag seperate.